# SQL Developer crashes in MacOS 2018

Tags: java, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

Just downloaded new version of SQL Developer 18.1.0.095.1630 for MacOS (currently running High Sierra 10.13.3 on MacBook pro laptop) and after opening it from Application folder - icon starts jumping and never opens and computer completly freezes.

That only happens with this app so wondering what is going on?!

I have JDK installed (1.8.0_162) and JAVA_HOME environment is set (to /Library/Java/Home).

It is annoying to hard-restart whole computer and still does not work.
At least would expect some error handling or popup error message from reputable software..

I tried increasing `ulimit` to max 64MB and still crashes.

How to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: The mouse pointer stops moving even when you try to move it?

Comment: Correct. Everything freezes.

Comment: If the mouse pointer stops being responsive (and the jumping icon stops jumping) and Cmd-Tab doesn't work any more, either the system is swapping to death or macOS has crashed or something of a similar severity.  It appears that 18.1.1 has been released - they might have fixed this.

Comment: Interesting.. Thanks for the info - I am not sure why is it happening with only SQL Dev app and only when try to open it.. All other apps work fine for hours.. Will check on new 18.1.1 version..

Comment: Do not see 18.1.1 version of SQL Developer (only for SQL client): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

Comment: What java version do you have ? in your console, type java -version

Comment: Java version is 1.8.0_162